# Vuejs table display axios filtered response

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been looking for a way to display filtered results in my table using vue js and axios. When i use an if statement on my table, the filtered results are displayed, but the problem comes in when i export the data because all the results, including the ones that are not filtered are extracted.
I am now filtering the axios response, but the table displays everything from my response. Any tips on methods i can use other than `filter` to obtain a filtered result will be appreciated.

My table

```
<v-data-table
                  :headers="headers1"
                  :items="new_users"
                  :rows-per-page-items="rowsPerPage"
                  :search="search"
                  :loading="true"
                  class="elevation-1"
                  item-key="id"
                >

                <template slot='no-data'>
                    <v-progress-linear slot='progress' indeterminate></v-progress-linear>
                </template>

                  <template
                    slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                    <!-- v-if="props.item.profile_complete === 0"> -->
                      <td>{{ props.item.gender }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.msisdn }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.profile_complete }}</td>
```

My computed property :

```
computed: {
    filteredList() {
      let self = this;
      this.new_users = this.users_ttl.filter(item => item.profile_complete === 0);
    }
  },
```

My method

```
getUsers () {
      axios.get('users')
        .then((response) => {
          this.users_ttl = response.data.data
          this.loopT(response.data.links.next)
          this.isLoading = false
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
          this.error = true

        })
    },
```

Comment: Could you try to explain your problem a bit better, I don'tt really understand what your exact question is. also your computed property isn't returning anything. shouldnt you return the result of the filter and use filteredList in your items attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computed property is currently not doing anything. You are not using it in the template. It also does not return a value and data is being mutated in it, which is a bad practice.

Replace the computed property you have with this

```js
computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.users_ttl.filter(item => item.profile_complete === 0);
    }
  },
```

And in your template, you can use the filtered list as follows

```html
<v-data-table
  ...
  :items="filteredList"
  ...
>
...
```